# How to convert latin characters into the english characters?

Tags: php, magento2.2.6, utf-8

I have following brand name which contains Latin character. How to convert the brand name into English?

Latin characterise string:  `RéVive LeurCrème`

Want to convert into - `Revive LeurCreme`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the latin-chars into standard english chars using  [transliterator_transliterate](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) Library. you mush have **intl** PHP extension installed, which is also mandatory for Magento.

```
$anyLatinString = utf8_encode('RéVive LeurCrème'); 
$transliteratedString = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII;', $anyLatinString);
// returns Revive LeurCreme
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use Normalizer PHP Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php)

```
<?php
$string = 'Höhle';
echo Normalizer::normalize($string);
?>
```